# Install pdfroff on macOS

Tags: terminal, install, homebrew

What's the recommended way to get the `pdfroff` command working on macOS?

It appears `groff` v1.19.2 comes still bundled with macOS 10.13, but `pdfroff` not anymore. So do I need to reinstall the entire `groff` [using homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/groff). Or is there a better way?

There is also this [pdfroff.sh script on opensource.apple.com](https://opensource.apple.com/source/groff/groff-39/groff/contrib/pdfmark/pdfroff.sh), which seems to work when executed with `sh pdfroff`.

Comment: What does running `type -a awk` output?

Comment: Any concern with installing groff from Homebrew? It appears thats the only way to get pdfroff.

Comment: @Nimesh, ah, with `sh pdfroff` it seems to work, as opposed to `./pdfroff`

Comment: if that's the best way I'll go with homebrew, just thought it would be nice to use the builtin groff, since it's alreadyd there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is recommend to install `groff` from Homebrew.

Apple's built-in `groff` is pretty outdated (version 1.19.2) and doesn't include `pdfroff`.

Homebrew's supplied version on the other hand is up-to-date with recent version available (version 1.22.3).

Install the required packages (GNU troff and Ghostscript) by running:

```
brew install groff gs
```

Comment: Yes, groff 1.19 seems to be from 2005 or something. I also needed to install GhostScript: `brew install gs`

Comment: If you are looking to work with most up-to-date UNIX tools, Homebrew is the way to go. Apple supplied tools are not updated very frequently.