# What's the simplest way to process files with UTF-8 characters in groff on macOS?

Tags: terminal, utf-8

I require Polish diacritics, such as ą, ć, ę, etc.

Of course, I can always pre-process the file to replace UTF-8 characters with escaped characters but that's not elegant.

Comment: you mean like this  (press and hold) then pick one ç ,ć, č, ß, ś, š

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The problem is not to enter the characters into the .ms file but to have groff render then properly in PS  output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of today, macOS Mojave ships with a quite outdated version of `groff` (1.19 or something...) which apparently cannot handle the `-K` option. Thus it fails to recognise any fancy diacritics (german umlauts in my case), if you run `groff -Kutf8 ...`.

You can get a newer version of groff on macOS by installing it via Homebrew, [as per this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/335814/292887)

```
brew install groff gs
```

(not sure if `gs` for ghostscript is actually required; I installed it anyway)

Comment: The `-k` alone option ("Process with `preconv`") _seems_ to do the right thing without having to specify the encoding, at least for my very simple use case of Unicode ellipses. However, `-Tutf8` is still required to display the actual UTF-8 characters properly in the terminal.

Comment: Apple was using old versions because of GPL 3. Ventura removes groff completely.

Answer (score 1):

The following convoluted way works:

```
groff -Kutf8 -Tdvi -mec -ms test.ms > test.dvi
dvipdfm -cz 9 test.dvi
open test.pdf
```

Via the [[Groff] latin2 polish special characters thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/groff/2007-09/msg00173.html) on lists.gnu.org.